# SQL Server stored procedure restore my records if Insert failed

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want to know if there is a way to state rollback the delete if I can not insert.

Please advice.

Something like below.

```
BEGIN TRAN
Delete from MYTABLE where ID=@ID;

INSERT INTO MYTABLE (ID, NAME)
SELECT @ID, NAME

COMMIT
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can put your two statements into a `TRY....CATCH` block and only commit if both statements succeed:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
BEGIN TRY
    DELETE FROM dbo.MYTABLE WHERE ID=@ID;

    INSERT INTO dbo.MYTABLE (ID, NAME)
       SELECT @ID, NAME

    -- COMMIT only if both DELETE and INSERT worked ....
    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT 
        ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber,
        ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity,
        ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState,
        ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure,
        ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine,
        ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage

    -- ROLLBACK if either DELETE and INSERT failed ....
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END CATCH
```

Comment: Only rolls back one row. the rest of them are gone :( can we do that for the whole life cycle of the stored procedure?

Comment: That is the whole life cycle of your sp. If you are talking about running the sp multiple times and rolling them all back if one errors, then you should change your process to process sets of data not rows.

Comment: Hmm I used table valued param and now it is wroking. So this is for only one row ..

Comment: No way - this rolls back **all rows** that have been deleted - trust me

Answer (score 3):

Turn [xact_abort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188792.aspx) on to rollback the transaction on any error.

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON;
BEGIN TRAN
Delete from MYTABLE where ID=@ID;

INSERT INTO MYTABLE (ID, NAME)
SELECT @ID, NAME

COMMIT TRAN
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to accomplish what you appear to be trying:

```
update myTable
set name = @name
where id = @id
```

Comment: although this is a good method, but it is update, I am looking for a particular way to delete and insert run my stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

```
BEGIN TRAN

Delete from MYTABLE where ID=@ID;

INSERT INTO MYTABLE (ID, NAME)
SELECT @ID, NAME

if @@error = 0 and @@trancount > 0
    commit
else
    rollback
```

Comment: This is incorrect and uses syntax that shoudl no longer be used now that we have TRYCATCH blocks. This willnot rollback if the delte fails. If you use @@error, you must check it after every  statement.

Comment: It is not incorrect. It will work and solves the problem as stated. The problem statement was to rollback the delete if the insert failed, so only checking after the insert is called for. Try..catch could also be used, but is not necessary.